# How can I load more messages and still keep the listener listening for new message events?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app chat using Firebase Real-time Database. Everything is ok before I want to add 'load more' feature. Currently, I get newest message (if someone send message) by `dbReference.child(childPath).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);`. This way will help getting newest message through func `onChildAdded`, but it also gets all messages in the child.

In short, I want the chat activity of the app to be able to get a number of old messages when start Activity or when I scroll to the top, and listen to the event with new messages. Do you have a way to solve this case? Below is the code I use to load newest messages, but it also retrieves all messages in conversation when I start activity.

[image: This is db structure]

```
private void getConversations() {
    dbReference = dbHelper.getDatabaseReference();
    String childPath = "/" + FirebaseDatabaseKeyName.CONVERSATIONS.getKeyName()
            + "/" + conversationId
            + "/" + FirebaseDatabaseKeyName.MESSAGES.getKeyName();

    dbReference.child(childPath).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Map<String, Object> objectMap = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Message message = Message.convertObjectMap(objectMap);
            if (message != null) {
                message.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                adapter.addMessage(message);
                smoothScrollEnd();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: In the meanwhile, instead of describing the code, please add it as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: I editted my question, the void 'getConversations' I use to load newest messages currently, but it also retrieves all of message in conversation.

Comment: Please also add your database structure.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, thank you.